# Knowing which custom UITableViewCellhas changed it's UiSwitch value?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

i've a custom UiTableViewCell that has a UiSwitch and a UILabel.
i wan to know the row and section of the UISwitch when it changes from on to of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find out the row & section from the UITableViewCell:

```
- (void)switchValueChanged:(id)sender {
  UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[[sender superview] superview];
  NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
  //.....
}
```

Comment: How can i get the ponint of the cell?

Comment: that's a good point - i've changed my original answer. hopefully that'll be better.